# Session File Permissions - Read/Write across accounts

Tags: php, session, file-permissions

I am attempting to share Sessions across sub domains, that are also their own accounts.

```
www.example.com 
kb.example.com
```

The code I am using to do this is

```
<?php

    ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com");

     // this was setting the session file to 0644 even though i was attempting 0777
    //ini_set('session.save_path', '0;777;' . session_save_path()); 

    session_start();

    // this modifies the session files permissions correctly
    $path = session_save_path() . '/sess_' . session_id();
    chmod($path, 0777);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';

    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;

    echo session_id();

?>
```

If I run this code on `www.example.com` can read the session information just fine, if I then run the same code on `kb.example.com` I will get the following errors

```
PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /home/kbexample/public_html/test.php on line 8

PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I read/write session data across these domains? Why can I not read the file even though its 0777?

Comment: Is changing permissions necessary? Are there separate processes run by different users serving each subdomain? Is `session.save_path` same in both cases?

Comment: @baf I attempted this with out changing the permissions with the same results.  They are indeed run by different users for each subdomain. The save path is `/tmp` in both cases.

Comment: Maybe `session_name` differs in both cases?